# Ajaxtoolkit not working when using masterpage .net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I am using .net 4.5 . I have ajaxtoolkit code that works when the asp.net page is not using a masterpage.  when i place the same ajaxtoolkit code inside a page that's not using a masterpage, the code works fine.

the error i get is:

This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add .

what?

the ajaxtoolkit code

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager> 

<ajaxToolkit:Twitter ID="Twitter1"  ScreenName="myscreenname"  Mode="Profile" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:Twitter>
```

Comment: Is `head` tag on a master page nested in `ContentPlaceholder` control?

Answer (score 1):

add below one..

```
<head runat="server">
```

may it helps you

Comment: not exactly.  this wouldn't explain why the code works outside of a masterpage.  the code outside of the masterpage doesnt have <head runat="server">